# Find no of days gap for a specific ID when it has a flag X in other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate the no. of days gap for when the 'flag' column is equal to 'X' for same IDs.

The dataframe that I have:

```
ID      Date        flag
1       1-1-2020    X
1       10-1-2020   null
1       15-1-2020   X
2       1-2-2020    X
2       10-2-2020   X 
2       15-2-2020   X
3       15-2-2020   null
```

The dataframe I want:

```
ID      Date        flag     no_of_days
1       1-1-2020    X        14
1       10-1-2020   null     null
1       15-1-2020   X        null
2       1-2-2020    X        9
2       10-2-2020   X        8
2       18-2-2020   X        null
3       15-2-2020   null     null
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter rows by `X` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then subtract shifted column per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and last convert timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df['new'] = df[df['flag'].eq('X')].groupby('ID')['Date'].shift(-1).sub(df['Date']).dt.days
print (df)
   ID       Date flag   new
0   1 2020-01-01    X  14.0
1   1 2020-01-10  NaN   NaN
2   1 2020-01-15    X   NaN
3   2 2020-02-01    X   9.0
4   2 2020-02-10    X   8.0
5   2 2020-02-18    X   NaN
6   3 2020-02-15  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you suggest me a book to get good at python especially for this kinda stuff?

Comment: @yellow_smile - You can check [this tutorials](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/index.html)